# What is the term for a child that's in between toddler and adolescent?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm trying to come up with terms to describe the various age ranges for children up through teenager and I'm stuck trying to describe someone who's in the age range of about 6 through 10. In other words, I'm trying to fill in the gap:

newborn -> infant -> toddler -> ??? -> pre-teen -> teenager

I considered that "pre-teen" technically fits that age range, but to me, that term strongly implies a child in the 10-12 range (just before they hit 13 and become a teenager). I also considered but rejected "pre-pubescent", which also technically fits, but is more focused on a child's level of sexual maturity, which is irrelevant to the situation I'm trying to describe.

Most references I found simply refer to children of that age as a "child", but doesn't that term apply equally to anyone under the age of majority, or at the very least, anyone pre-adolescence?

Comment: ............. tween ...........

Comment: 'Child' for me covers infant to teenager but feels best for the range toddler to pre-teen (if you see a sixth month old I would tend to call them a baby not a child, even though 'child' is not wrong; words can have overlapping semantic contexts). So 'child' would fit '??' best for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think *[preschooler  and school-aged](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_development)* can define that stage of a child:

Some age-related development periods and examples of defined intervals are:

> newborn (ages 0–4 weeks);
>
> infant (ages 4 weeks – 1 year);
>
> toddler (ages 1–3 years);
>
> *preschooler (ages 4–6 years);*
>
> school-aged child (ages 6–13 years);
>
> adolescent (ages 13–19).

Comment: I'm trying to find terms that are independent of attending school, though I suspect those terms would be generally recognizable on their own. Those might work.

Comment: I'd amend that slightly to `0 ≤ infant ≤ 1 ≤ toddler ≤ 3 ≤ preschooler ≤ 5-6 ≤ school-aged child/schoolboy or schoolgirl ≤ 9-10 ≤ tween / pre-teen ≤ 12 ≤ teen` as it depends on the kid & the school district.